# Laravel Custom validation redirection with errors and custom data

Tags: php, laravel, validation

How do I redirect the response of Custom Request validation class to a custom page with the errors and some custom data.

The response method in the code below is not working.

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Requests;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Http\FormRequest;

class employeeStore extends FormRequest {

    public function authorize() {
        return true;
    }

    public function rules() {
        return [
            'contacts' => 'bail|required|array|min:2',
            'contacts.*.contact_no' => 'bail|required|regex:/[7-9][0-9]{9}/',
            'contacts.*.is_preferred' => 'in:true,false',
        ];
    }

    public function messages() {
        return [
            'contacts.min' => 'provide at-least one alternate mobile no',
            'contacts.*.contact_no.required' => 'this field is required',
            'contacts.*.contact_no.regex' => 'mobile number entered is not valid',
        ];
    }

    public function response(array $errors)
    {
        if ($this->ajax() || $this->wantsJson())
        {
            return new JsonResponse($errors, 422);
        }
        return $this->redirector->to('profile')
            ->withInput($this->except($this->dontFlash))
            ->withErrors($errors, $this->errorBag);
    }

}
```

Comment: What exactly does not work? the redirect?

Comment: Yes the redirect is not working.

Comment: Well it does work for me, are you getting any error?

Comment: `return redirect()->route('profile',array('input' => $this->except($this->dontFlash),'errors' => $errors));` This is the normal redirect approach

Comment: can you try this one `return redirect()->to('profile')
                    ->withInput($this->except($this->dontFlash))
                    ->withErrors($errors, $this->errorBag);`